# How to inherit/combine enumerations in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have elements which can face North, South, East, West (4 rotation values) and elements which can face N, S, E, W, NE, SE, SW, NW (8 rotation values).

I am trying to inherit 8 rotation values from 4 rotation values, but I can't.

What is the correct syntax?

```
<xs:simpleType name="direction4">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
    <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="90"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="180"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="270"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="direction8">
    <xs:restriction base="direction4">
        <xs:enumeration value="45"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="135"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="225"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="315"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a natural case for `xs:union`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="direction90">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="90"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="180"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="270"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="direction45">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:enumeration value="45"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="135"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="225"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="315"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="direction8">
    <xs:union memberTypes="direction90 direction45"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```